# PushDown Automata tag misuse

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

I've seen several examples when people asking question about mobile/handheld devices use tag [pda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pda). Apparently thinking that it is acronym for Personal Digital Assistant, but this tag meant to be used with PushDown Automata questions.
Frankly speaking at first glance I thought the same until I checked tag excerpt.

It is an ambiguous tag name that produce such mistakes and I think it should be solved somehow. Either by renaming [pda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pda)(i.e.: without using acronyms) or by using [tag-tips](/questions/tagged/tag-tips).

Handheld devices have their own tags: [handheld](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/handheld)[handhelddevice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/handhelddevice) also [smart-device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smart-device)and I think they will be used more often instead of the [pda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pda) tag.

Comment: I think renaming `pda` is the best option here. Only people who have studied automata theory think of pushdown automata when seeing the abbreviation. Also, the handheld and related tag seems to be a good target for burnination.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bit interesting. There were 80 questions tagged [pda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pda). Started out with the first page and it had just Push down automata related questions. However reality hit me hard on the second page. There were 30 questions out of which

- 12 were related to Windows' PDA. Unsurprisingly most of those were actually off topic. I closed and deleted them. Some of them were already tagged [windows-ce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-ce). I tagged the remaining (2) with [windows-ce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-ce), as they were related to the Windows CE PDA.
- 2 were related to Pocket PC, which I tagged with [pocketpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pocketpc)
- 1 was related to the Windows magnification API, which I tagged with [magnification-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magnification-api)
- 6 were related to digital assistants, but the fact that it was related to a PDA was not worthy of a tag, so I just removed the tag.
- 5 questions were about Personal Digital Assistants in general, which I tagged with [handhelddevice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/handhelddevice). I did not use [handheld](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/handheld) as it seemed in a really bad shape with questions related to completely different technologies.
- 1 other was completely unclear, so I just deleted it.

... and the remaining were related to Push Down Automata.

I merged the [pda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pda) tag to [pushdown-automaton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pushdown-automaton), as it is being used mainly for that these days (as well as more than 75% of the tag was for that). Most of the handheld device related questions were really old, and therefore I don't think any of the PDA tag would be recreated, but just to be sure, I added [pda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pda) as a synonym to the renamed tag.

I created a new [personal-digital-assistant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/personal-digital-assistant) and synonymized it to [handhelddevice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/handhelddevice), in case someone is still looking to type in "Personal Digital Assistant" in the tag space.